# Find $P(X+Y < \frac{1}{2})$ Given Joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The following question is the regular **problem 6.10** from **Sheldon Ross's "A first Course In Porbability"** book (Global Edition I think):

[image]

So, my question is: How do I solve both parts of this problem? Will there be double integrations?

Comment: You just need to integrate $f$ over the required ranges (double integrals, yes). So for example in $(a)$ we have $0\leqslant x<a$ and $0\leqslant y \leqslant 1$.

Comment: What about for part(b), is it a double integral over $0\leq x < \frac{1}{2} - Y$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$?

Comment: Yea, remember that means you need to do the $y$ integration first

Comment: Got it, thank you!